# How can I show results count on search results page in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I'm trying to display search results count in the result page in Drupal 8, I want to display something like: `23 results for search_word`.

I'm using the default Drupal search, and `item-list--search-results.html.twig` as the template file to display the results, but I can't find the search result count in the available variables, any idea how can find this value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no variable for results count in Drupal 8.

1) Add this variable using the following code (add this code to MYTHEME.theme):

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_item_list(&$variables) {

    $total = null;
  // get the total number of results from the $GLOBALS
  if(isset($GLOBALS['pager_total_items'])){
    $total = $GLOBALS['pager_total_items'][0];
  }

  $variables['count_items'] = $total;
}
```

2) Then you can use **{{ count_items }}** in **item-list--search-results.html.twig**:

```
<div> {{ count_items }} results for search_word </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default way the item-list file works is to loop through and array called items so you could do something like 
`<div> {{ items|length }} results printed </div>`

[Source](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html)

Comment: But this doesn't work if we have a pager in the page, because in this case the items array only holds single page items!

Comment: I would check out the Devel module then and see if you can find what array is holding the entire search results. That one has yet to let me down in Drupal 8 while adjusting to the new Twig shenanigans.